# Entity Framework combine custom tables and identity tables

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have created a business layer and data layer for a custom task management system. It just has 2 related tables `Tasks and TaskNotes`. Now, I would like to build an MVC application on top of it using the Individual User Accounts that you can specify for authentication (ASP.NET Identity).

What is the easiest way to get my tables and the identity tables into one database?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is to have one `DbContext` for all your entities.

You should add `Task` and `TaskNote` to your `ApplicationDbContext` which inherited from `IdentityDbContext`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public DbSet<Tasks> Tasks { set; get; }
    public DbSet<TaskNotes> TaskNotes { set; get; }
}
```